# Replace all occurances of a number in a matrix python

Tags: python, array-algorithms

The input is a multi-line string containing the matrix:

```
input = '''22 13 17 11  0
 8  2 23  4 24
21  9  7 16  7
 6 10  3  7  5
 1 12 20 15 19'''
```

I have to replace all the occurrences of, let's say 7 with -1. So the output array would be:

```
output = '''22 13 17 11  0
 8  2 23  4 24
21  9  -1 16  -1
 6 10  3  -1  5
 1 12 20 15 19'''
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried NumPy, list comprehension and a few different ways of iterating using a for-loop.

Comment: How about, ``input.replace('7', '-1')`` ?

Comment: @sushanth No, it would replace 17 too..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could keep it in string format and simply use a [word-separator regex](https://regex101.com/r/vEz0fJ/1) and [`sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) all the specific numbers you want:

```py
import re

s = '''22 13 17 11  0
 8  2 23  4 24
21  9  7 16  7
 6 10  3  7  5
 1 12 20 15 19'''

num = 7
target = -1
print(re.sub(rf'\b{num}\b', str(target), s))
```

Will give:

```
22 13 17 11  0
 8  2 23  4 24
21  9  -1 16  -1
 6 10  3  -1  5
 1 12 20 15 19
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try splitting it by spaces and then running a for loop.

```
s = '''22 13 17 11  0
 8  2 23  4 24
21  9  7 16  7
 6 10  3  7  5
 1 12 20 15 19'''

a = s.split(" ")
b = []
for i in a:
    if i == "7":
        b.append("-1")
    else:
        b.append(i)

c = " ".join(b)
print(c)
```

Comment: A nice little trick to remove the if check could be: `b.append({'7': '-1'}.get(i, i))`